# Reading Quran on behalf of another person

Tags: quran, reading-quran

Asalamualaikum.
My younger brother has been autistic at the age of 2 years old. Me and my family have been trying to teach him about being a Muslim and a normal citizen. But up until now, he's at the age of 16 and he hasn't gain any knowledge or practice of being a normal citizen or a Muslim. But me and my family are all Muslim. Since the time of Ramadan has arrived, I plan to read the Qur'an on his behalf since he cannot read despite the training we've given him over the past years due to his autism. Am I permissible to read Quran on his behalf or no? If not, what else should I do for him?
Jazak Allah Khair.

Answer (score 1):

There is disagreement on whether it is valid to gift the reward of reciting the Quran to another person.

The [Hanafis](https://shamela.ws/book/8183/535) and [Hanbalis](https://shamela.ws/book/622/1736) consider it permissible and valid, based on generalization from the texts:

> والذين جاءوا من بعدهم يقولون ربنا اغفر لنا ولإخواننا الذين سبقونا بالإيمان
>
> And [there is a share for] those who came after them, saying, "Our Lord, forgive us and our brothers who preceded us in faith ... "
>
> <sup>— [Quran 59:10](https://quran.com/59/10?translations=20)</sup>

> واستغفر لذنبك وللمؤمنين والمؤمنات
>
> Ask forgiveness for your sin and for the believing men and believing women.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 47:19](https://quran.com/47/19?translations=20)</sup>

> كان إذا أراد أن يضحي ... فذبح أحدهما عن أمته ...  وذبح الآخر عن محمد وعن آل محمد
>
> When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) wanted to offer a sacrifice ...  he slaughtered one on behalf of his nation ... and he slaughtered the other on behalf of Muhammad and the family of Muhammad (ﷺ).
>
> <sup>— [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3122) , [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1967)</sup>

> إنه لو كان مسلما فأعتقتم عنه أو تصدقتم عنه أو حججتم عنه بلغه ذلك
>
> Had he been a Muslim and you had emancipated slaves on his behalf, or given sadaqah on his behalf, or performed the pilgrimage, that would have reached him.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2883)</sup>

As they understand from these that the benefit of any act of worship can be given to another person.